# Wrong resolution for TV connected via HDMI (32LG3000)

Tags: 12.04, resolution, hdmi, tv, randr

I have a [LG Electronics 32LG3000](http://geizhals.de/eu/319737) TV. I can't select the right resolution for my TV connected via HDMI. I can select 1360x768 but not 1366x768. The quality on my TV is very bad.

```
HDMI1 connected 1360x768+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
   1360x768       59.8*+
   1920x1080      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x720       59.7  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1
```

---

I have a Intel 3000 graphic card and no settings menu like this

there are no restricted drivers for my mac.

Comment: Are you using multiple displays and cloning that of a pc monitor?

Answer (score 1):

As your TV accepts a (much higher quality) 1920 by 1080 input, I would suggest selecting this and allowing your television to downscale it to fit.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a limited number of resolutions for TVs and 1366x768 or 1360x768 isn't one I know of, but LG somehow managed to put something non-standard together and sell it as 32LG3000 and probably even more models. However common resolutions for TVs are 480p (640x480), 720p (1280x720) and 1080p (1920x1080).

There is the possibility to generate a custom modeline and feeding it to RandR, the application responsible for handling screen resolution and a lot more, to get the right resolution, but there is also a high possibility to destroy the TV with a bad modeline.

I'd like to say buy a TV with a standard display resolution, but I may be wrong on that too and shelves are full with TVs like these. :(

As you seem to be a german speaking user here you go: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/RandR

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [Televisions are awful](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/8705.html), so the only thing to do is to not use them as a computer display.